# pthread_join giving segmentation fault

Tags: c

Somehow my code is returning segmentation fault. sockfd is an int, or file descriptor

```
pthread_t tid[4];
int err;
int k = 0;
while (k < 4) {
    err = pthread_create(&tid[k], NULL, listen_connection, (void*) sockfd);
    k++;
}
pthread_join(tid[0], NULL); // causes segmentation fault
pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);
pthread_join(tid[2], NULL);
pthread_join(tid[3], NULL);

return 0;
```

Declaration of listen_connection:

```
void * listen_connection(void *);
```

Actual function:

```
void * listen_connection(void *sockfd) {

int newsockfd, n;
// client address
struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
socklen_t clilen;

newsockfd = accept(*(int*)sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
...
```

EDIT: I figured it out.

Instead of:

```
err = pthread_create(&tid[k], NULL, listen_connection, (void*) sockfd);
```

I changed it to:

```
err = pthread_create(&tid[k], NULL, listen_connection, (void*) &sockfd);
```

Comment: how do you know exactly `pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);` is causing segfault? did you use a debugger?

Comment: also, any reason you couldn't have used a `for` loop?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but if I comment out all the pthread_join lines then there are no segmentation faults.

Comment: Isn't that what I answered?

Comment: figure out how do you let the thread be terminated may also be helpful.

Comment: if someone answers your question correctly it's better to accept their answer, rather than edit your question with the answer (or if no one answers it correctly you can submit your own answer).  In this case it looks like @JS1 had the correct answer posted before you edited your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*(int *)sockfd` is wrong.  `sockfd` is not a pointer because you passed an int to pthread_create().  Either pass `&sockfd` to pthread_create(), or cast like this `(int) sockfd`.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is not likely to be caused by `pthread_join`. MAN page http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join `The pthread_join() function waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate` and `The thread specified by thread must be joinable.`

I think you should check anyway for the return value of the `pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);` statement to ensure it works as you expect. It should give an error number because your threads `tid[4]` are not joinable. You should create pthread attribute variable `pthread_attr_t attr;` followed by initialization of that attr variable `pthread_attr_init(&attr);` and finally use `pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);`. And you should create you threads using this attribute variable.

Comment: "By default, a new thread is created in a joinable state" http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create. So you don't need to set this explicitly.